# A little confusion about api

Tags: android

I am confused to understand that how we can call Android API, not other APIs like rest API, but Android API like API 21,22,23.

What we can call using Gradle?

Comment: Your question makes me think you don't understand the Android development at all. I would suggest you start with a tutorial. Millions of them are available online.

Comment: Maybe its time to hit the books? You'd need to learn and understand the basics first. I'd suggest you study and learn about APIs, software development (be it java, android anything you prefer) and REST APIs. Here's a few links to get you started: https://medium.com/@TebbaVonMathenstien/what-is-an-api-and-why-should-i-use-one-863c3365726b https://www.howtogeek.com/343877/what-is-an-api/ https://restfulapi.net/

Comment: Start with beginner programming books, or take a CS/Programming course or bootcamp etc to learn the basic topics. There are other sites offering to teach beginners & you should look into them, like udemy, reddit r/learnprogramming/ etc. Once you've grasped Object Oriented Programming you can move on to learning web technologies and apis like REST etc.

Comment: you can't call specific APi  version, as the phone will have only 1 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Android version is called on 21,22,23,24 etc.

Refer the below page -

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history